# Enforce collectionView to have only 2 rows

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I have to make one collection view so that irrespective of iphone size we have just 2 images in each row and also we need border between each row and column as shown in the image.

**I want like this:**

[image]

Comment: You could use `[myUICollectionViewFlowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake([self frame].size.width/2, [self frame].size.width/2)]; [myCollectionView collection setCollectionViewLayout: myUICollectionViewFlowLayout];`

Comment: can you post some code of what you've tried?

Answer (score 4):

Try this code. Just a different approach.

```
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

     let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
     layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 4, bottom: 6, right: 4)
     layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 04
     layout.minimumLineSpacing = 04
     layout.invalidateLayout()
     return CGSize(width: ((self.view.frame.width/2) - 6), height: ((self.view.frame.width / 2) - 6))
     }
```

Output from above code on different devices.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Implement the following functions from collectionView's protocol:

```
// cell size

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width/2, height: view.frame.size.width/2)
}
```

...where view is your controller's (super) view

```
// inter-spacing

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 2.0
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
        collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 2.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.* and Xcode 9.3**

If you are using multiple collectionView on same ViewController then you can use something as below -

```
// Height and Width for the cell
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                                        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
                if collectionView.tag == 101 {
                    return CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
                }
                else if collectionView.tag == 102 {
                    return CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width/2, height: view.frame.size.width/2)
                }
                else {
                    return CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
                }

            }

    // InterItemSpacing
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                                minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
                if collectionView.tag == 101 {
                    return 5.0
                }
                else if collectionView.tag == 102 {
                    return 0.0
                }
                else {
                    return 5.0
                }
            }

    // InterLineSpacing
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
                collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                                minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
                if collectionView.tag == 101 {
                    return 5.0
                }
                else if collectionView.tag == 102 {
                    return 0.0
                }
                else {
                    return 5.0
                }
            }
```