# Collection View positioning like instagram app swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard

I’ve been programming app like instagram for learn swift and ios programming. Now I’d created UIStackView that would be a top bar, and 3 bottom buttons that posts requests and change images.

The problem that I have - I can’t set position, width and delete cell spacing on CollectionView. I want to:
CollectionView full width on all devices
cell spacing between images = 1
CollectionView should be positioned between top bar and bottom buttons full height

What did I have now?

screen of my emulator: http://prntscr.com/d1mmu1

screen of my storyboard: http://prntscr.com/d1mnhr

I’d tried do this with StoryBoard, had changed all of parametres but hasnt reached my goals.
If I add equal height to CollectionView and main view of app it takes all screen and after scrolling it disapears…
How can I set that position and width, height, and cell spacing on it?

```
here is a code of my viewcontroller for CollectionView -
```

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

```
// tell the collection view how many cells to make
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "main/p\(self.items[indexPath.item].code)/main/main.jpg")
    print("main_card_images/p\(self.items[indexPath.item].code)/main/main")
    return cell
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    print(self.items[indexPath.item])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let yourNextViewController = (segue.destination as! ViewControllerCard)
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: sender as! UICollectionViewCell)
    yourNextViewController.mainCardImage = self.items[(indexPath?.item)!]
}
```

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325327/adjust-cellsize-for-fit-all-screens/40325452#40325452

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code.**

**Note :** Below code works only for 4 column layout tested on all iPhone models.If you want different number of column.You need to play with cell width and height or look at my other answer [Adjust cellsize for fit all screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325327/adjust-cellsize-for-fit-all-screens/40325452#40325452)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 3, left: 3, bottom: 3, right: 3)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 03
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 03
    layout.invalidateLayout()

    return CGSize(width: ((self.view.frame.width/4) - 4), height:((self.view.frame.width / 4) - 4));
}
```

Output:

[image]