# In UICollectionViewCell need to set border effect where it cross to each others (Junction type)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I implement the UICollectionViewCell. Now I need to set border effect where the cell cross to each others like junction point.

here is the image, which I need to set border like this..

[image]

I tried out to give cell border but in output left & right side border is appear which is not my desired output. 
So my output look like this. (Wrong output)

[image]

So please help me..

Comment: I think once you set UICollectionView background colour as per your boarder colour. May your problem will solved. Try it.

Comment: @YagneshDobariya I already check with changed background color, but when scrolling at that time background color is visible

Comment: For that you can disable bounces effect in UICollection from Storyboard or programmatically.

Comment: are you trying to achieve a `parallax effect`? or just a `static border`.

Comment: @Joe Just static border..

Comment: can you explain your problem in short.its hard to understand your problem?. are you having problem with only outside border or post your tried code  may help to solve your issue

Comment: I need to only set middle border '+' without outside border(Left&Right)

Comment: can you post your collectionView frame size?

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: CGFloat(collectionView.frame.size.width / 2 - 0.5 ), height: CGFloat(170))
    }

Comment: i mean frame size not contentSize....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152247/discussion-between-niravs-and-joe).

Comment: Ya your code is working..

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Below answer based on the discussion between question owner and myself.

You need to setup a `collectionViewFlowLayout` properly to achieve the desired output. Try below code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // All the values are changable according to your needs.
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 2
    return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView.frame.width / 2) - 1 , height:(self.collectionView.frame.height / 3) - 1)
}
```

**Update 1:** Calculating layout includes `navigationBar` and `StatusBar`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // All the values are changable according to your needs.
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 2
    return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView.frame.width / 2) - 1 , height:(((self.view.frame.height - ((navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)) / 3) - 1))
}
```

You may need to validate collectionView frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
 collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}
```

Following link may help you to understand the `collectionViewFlowLayout`.

[Enforce collectionView to have only 2 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131349/enforce-collectionview-to-have-only-2-rows/40133928#40133928)

[uicollectionview remove top padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023384/uicollectionview-remove-top-padding/43025517#43025517)

[Adjust cellsize for fit all screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325327/adjust-cellsize-for-fit-all-screens/40325452#40325452)

**Note:** In future, Post your question with relevant code and state problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

setting border will not give the desired result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4iiS.png)

cgfloat  intcellSize = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/3)-0.8;

now inside this method define it:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if ((mutArrContact.count%3) == 0) {

            return (mutArrContact.count/3) * intcellSize ;
        }
        else
        {
            return ((mutArrContact.count/3) * intcellSize)+ intcellSize;
        }

}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return CGSizeMake (intcellSize,intcellSize);
}
```

This is for displaing 3 cells with the desired result.