# UICollectionView cell reusability issue - swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[VC code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUniF.png)
[Overlapping text label issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZe4C.png)

I am using Collection View for my application. I am facing cell reusability issue. I am taking a separate class for UICollectionViewCell and I have bound the outlets. Please refer the code snippet below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionview: UICollectionView!

// An array to create desired number of cells in the home screen collection view 

let category = ["About Us", "Program Structure", "Courses", "Linkedin" , "Latest News", "Contact Us","Facebook", "Twitter", "Youtube", "Student Portal", "Alumni", "Faculty", "Career Center", "Free Software", "Apply Now", "FAQ"]

let imagearray = [UIImage (named: "Entypo_d83d(1)_512"), UIImage (named: "Entypo_d83d(0)_1024-6"), UIImage (named: "Entypo_d83d(0)_1024"), UIImage (named: "Entypo_f318(0)_1024"), UIImage (named: "Entypo_e776(0)_1024"), UIImage (named: "Entypo_d83d(0)_1024-2"),UIImage (named: "Entypo_f30c(0)_1024"), UIImage (named: "Entypo_f309(0)_1024"), UIImage (named: "Entypo_d83c(0)_1024-1"), UIImage (named: "Entypo_e78e(0)_1024"), UIImage (named: "Entypo_e722(0)_1024"), UIImage (named: "Entypo_d83d(0)_1024-1"), UIImage (named: "Entypo_d83d(0)_1024-3"), UIImage (named: "Entypo_d83d(0)_1024-4"), UIImage (named: "Entypo_e789(0)_1024"), UIImage (named: "Entypo_d83d(0)_1024-5")]

let webarray = ["http://ed.fullerton.edu/msidt/about-our-department/", "http://ed.fullerton.edu/msidt/future-students/program-structure/", "http://ed.fullerton.edu/msidt/future-students/courses/", "https://www.linkedin.com/in/msidt-csuf-9ab982119", "http://ed.fullerton.edu/msidt/category/news/", "http://ed.fullerton.edu/msidt/about-our-department/contact-information/", "https://www.facebook.com/MSIDTFullerton/", "https://twitter.com/msidt", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAu_Ef22gvA", "https://shibboleth.fullerton.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO?execution=e1s1", "http://ed.fullerton.edu/msidt/alumni/", "http://ed.fullerton.edu/msidt/faculty/", "http://www.fullerton.edu/career/", "http://www.fullerton.edu/it/students/software/", "http://ed.fullerton.edu/msidt/apply-now/", "http://ed.fullerton.edu/msidt/future-students/faq/"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.     
}

//to set the number of cells

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.category.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell1

    cell.imageopenview.image = self.imagearray[indexPath.item]

    cell.titlelabel .text = self.category[indexPath.item]

    return cell   
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newVC") as! NewViewController
    secondViewController.strUrl = webarray[indexPath.item]
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)

 }
}
```

I badly need the help. Please provide me the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add your `CollectionViewCell1` class and check the value of `cell` variable by printing it.

Comment: Your code not explaining the problem.can you post your collectionViewCell class and state the issue when you run the project...

Comment: @Joe here's my complete code snippet. I have edited the code in my question. When I run the app each cell has a label which comes from the array "category". When I scroll up and down I can see that the label text gets overlapped onto each other. So can you please help me in solving this problem?

Comment: Your code looks alright to me but I am not sure about your other class. From your code you simple passing the URL link to your 2ndVC.r u using webView to load this URL?..your code not explaining your problem.let me know what problem you facing...

Comment: But from your above code you can't pass data to your 2ndVC.because you haven't assigned the data string  like var strUrl = string() on mainVC and 2ndVC...

Comment: @Joe Yeah the code works fine and its only on the cells in the collectionview screen that the problem arises when I run the app the main screen which has different cells with a text label and image seems to overlap when you scroll through them. The code snippet of the othe VC is

Comment: class NewViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var website: UIWebView!
  
    var strUrl : NSString = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(strUrl)
        
        let url = NSURL (string: strUrl as String);
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        website.loadRequest(requestObj)
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "MSIDT", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        website.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
    }

Comment: Can you post this code into your post. So I can get a better look...

Comment: I think you hav collectionView layout issue.so can post your screenshot of your collectionView o/p..

Comment: @Joe I have added the screenshot of the code and my problem. Please have a look. Thank you so much

Comment: i  just looked your screenshot...look at my answer on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131349/enforce-collectionview-to-have-only-2-rows/40133928#40133928  let me know what you thing....

Comment: its just a layout issue....dont place a ur label top of each other .just reposition your labels.....

Comment: @Joe Oh thank you so much. I will look at it and try it out and let u know the updates. Thanks a million. U are a life saver

Comment: If my other answer helped you to find the solution give me an upvote..good luck....

Comment: @Joe I tried changing the label but it doesn't work. I have just one label on top of the image view. What would be the possible problem? this small thing is stopping me to push my app to the app store.Any suggestions

Comment: @Joe Any help on this?

Comment: Can you post your collectionViewCell class.did you try autoConstrains your label?

Comment: @Joe can you share any other contact information of yours so that its easy for me to share my code and communicate. I cant do much here as i am new and don't have much options to chat

Comment: I recommend you to repost your question.so some one will come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `CollectionViewCell1` class

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    titlelabel.text = nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. but I have already used this 
override func prepareForReuse() -> Void {
        imageopenview.image = nil
        titlelabel.text=nil
    }

Comment: No it doesn't. Plz help